# Fetch data from DB based on POST data using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I'm trying to fetch data from db based on POST data, but I get some weird error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Im pretty sure something is wrong with my data query  - wrong syntax / wrong types, but I can not var_dump variable values, so I'm kinda clueless.

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$data = [];
$ajax_test = [];

if(isset($_POST['checkboxList'])){
$data = $_POST['checkboxList']; // Possible results: 1; 12; 123 (checkbox value)
}
if(isset($_POST['thisisajax'])){
$ajax_test = $_POST['thisisajax'];
}

if($ajax_test){
 $db = JFactory::getDbo();
 $query = $db->getQuery(true);
 $query->select('*');
 $query->from($db->quoteName('#__products'));
 $query->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = (', implode(",",$data));
 // var_dump($query->__toString()); Doesnt work... Why?
 $db->setQuery($query);
 $results = $db->loadObjectList();
 $response = $data;

echo new JResponseJson($response);
jexit();
}

?>

<form method="post" action="" name="form1" id="mycustomform">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="1"> Apple</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="2"> Pineapple</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxList[]" onclick="function1();" value="3"> Pen</input>
</form>
<div id="response"></div>

<script>
function function1() {
var data = jQuery("#mycustomform").serialize() + '&thisisajax=1';
console.log(data);
jQuery.ajax({
url: "<?php echo JUri::current(); ?>", 
type: "POST",
data: data, 
success: function(response){ 
response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
if(response.success === true){
jQuery('#response').html(response.data);
} else {
alert('error');
}
}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: try this `data: JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: Check raw output of your script in developers console

Comment: You can still still var_dump. You go to chrome inspector's network tab and click on xhr which will have a response tab where you can see the server response.